# Connection to Azure Logic App is closed by remost host

Tags: .net, vsto, httpwebrequest, azure-logic-apps

Early in January, I developed a very simple Logic App which takes an HTTPS trigger as an entry point. This Logic App simply takes a GET request, sends me an email, and then returns a 200 OK response to the client.

I use it in conjunction with a VSTO add-in which calls the Logic App each time it is installed; so that I get a sense of growth. I did not receive any emails since early February, only then to recently discover this was because every time the VSTO add-in tries to call the trigger, it now returns a "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at ExcelAddIn...
>
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   <---

The code within the VSTO addin has not changed since January, nor has the Logic App changed either. It was working fine for all clients, and is now not working for any of them. What I am even more surprised about, is that the Logic App log does not show any failed calls either.

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4.0 then SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 and SecurityProtocolType.Tls2 are not defined so instead you can use the hard coded value below.

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

Comment: @Ama - did it helped you?
I'm having the same issue